# Update Query using SELECT results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

As my application is expanding, I now am changing the structure of my database; I now want to control file types within the database.  I wanted to start with the current file types already in the database.  My Database now has a [simplified] 2 table structure like:

`tbFiles: pkFileID, fileType, fileName`

`tblFileType: pkFileType, typeName, typeDesc`

I am trying to have the output of a `SELECT` query update into the newly created `tblFileType` table.  I have tried among other things:

```
UPDATE tblFileType
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT fileType FROM tblFiles) as X
SET typeName = fileType
```

but I always seem to get `0 row(s) affected`.

When I run

```
SELECT DISTINCT fileType
FROM  `tblFiles`
```

I get `Showing rows 0 - 22 (~23 total, Query took 0.0074 sec)`

I know this must be simple, but why is the UPDATE query not affecting 23 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `JOIN` condition like `ON t1.fileType = x.fileType` as follows:

```
UPDATE tblFileType t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT fileType 
    FROM tblFiles
)as X ON t1.fileType = x.fileType
SET t1.typeName = X.fileType
```

**Update:** Since the table `tblFileType` is blank, you will need to use `INSERT` something like:

```
INSERT INTO tblFileType(typeName )
SELECT DISTINCT fileType 
FROM tblFiles
WHERE -- a condition here
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I originally had an `ON` clause of `1=1`, but it didn't do anything.  Your query as shown has an `ON` clause, but the table `tblFileType` is blank, so there is nothing to match records with the `ON`.  When making small corrections to the Query above (t1.fileType -> t1.typeName, x.fileType -> X.fileType, ) , I still get 0 Records returned.

Comment: @SableFoste You can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` see my edit.

Comment: thank you very much, that was it!  I knew it was obvious; sometimes I just get a 'duh' moment!

Answer (score 1):

you just want to populate the table - not update anything in there (especially since nothing exists yet)

```
INSERT INTO tblFileType(typeName )
SELECT DISTINCT fileType FROM tblFiles
```